# How to Create Unique Lists?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, pivot-table, excel-2016

I've been attempting to take a list of emails, then find all possible related emails attached to those emails. For example, I might have a list that looks like this:

| SME | Backup | Comp | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person A | Person B | Person C | Person D | Person E |
| Person A | Person B | Person F | Person G |  |
| Person A | Person B | Person F | Person H |  |

What I would like to turn that into is this:

| SME | CONTACTS |
| --- | --- |
| Person A | Person B; Person C; Person D; Person E; Person F; Person G; Person H |

Basically, get a unique list of individuals associated with this particular SME. Of course, there are multiple SMEs in my actual data, so I would need to loop this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  [Dictionary Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub macro1()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsIn As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet, cell As Range
    Dim dict As Object, key, SME As String, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim ar As Variant

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsIn = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' put data into array
    ar = wsIn.UsedRange.Value2

    ' input
    For r = 2 To UBound(ar) '2 - avoid hedaer
        SME = Trim(ar(r, 1))
        For c = 1 To UBound(ar, 2)
            If Len(ar(r, c)) > 0 Then
                If c = 1 Then
                    If Not dict.exists(SME) Then
                        Set dict(SME) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                    End If
                Else
                    dict(SME)(ar(r, c)) = 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ' output
    With wsOut
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("A1:B1") = Array("SME", "CONTACTS")
        .Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
        Set cell = .Range("A2")
    End With
    For Each key In dict.keys
        cell = key
        cell.Offset(0, 1) = Join(dict(key).keys, "; ")
        Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
    Next
    wsOut.Activate
    wsOut.Range("A1").Select
    MsgBox dict.Count & " SMEs written to " & wsOut.Name, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need VBA to do this, take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LOsQFipqkw

You also can do it using Power Query:

- Load the table into Power Query
- Select all columns except the first
- Unpivot Columns
- Remove unnecessary columns
- Remove Duplicate rows
- Close and Load

[image]